# The difference between these two...?

Tags: php, mysql

First time I searched for how to connect to databases with PHP I've stumbled upon this example:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
```

But what's the difference between that and this?

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference form user perspective actually. The variable-in-double-quote will be evaluated, so;

```
$hello="world";
$world="hello"; 
echo "$hello $world"
```

will print "world hello".

This feature allows you to do

`"$very $annoying $string"`
 instead of 
`$very." ".$annoying." ".$string`

This is like shell script (if you're familiar with shell script).

Comment: This is the most understandable answer for me. I will accept this one. Thank you for clarifying this. You also helped me a lot with reducing the amounts of dots in my string literals.

Answer (score 3):

`"$var"` is complete nonsense. That's a string with the value of `$var` substituted. If the string doesn't contain anything but `$var`, it's identical to `$var`:

```
$var = "foo";
$nonsense = "$var"; // → "foo"
```

`"$var" == $var`. Use the `$var` as is, no need to wrap it in a string. It's faster, too.

Comment: As a complementary answer (non-related), use `"$var"` only if you want to use a `$var` inside a string. `"Hello, my name is $name!"` is equivalent to `'Hello, my name is ' . $name . '!'`.

Comment: Also as complementary extension, if `$var` is not already a string it'll be cast to a string, which may change the value (arrays for example). You wouldn't usually do this with arrays anyway though, so it's completely useless almost all of the time. If you'd want to explicitly cast to a string, `(string)$var` is usually preferred.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that in the first line PHP needs to process the strings and checks if there are variables menitioned in them and replace the variables with their respective values.

You can read more about this here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

**Edit**

But as mentioned, the output will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The result of it will be exactly the same! So don't worry about it. But if you should choose between them, you should choose the second.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of result unless , in the second one is not of datatype `string`.

The first one `"$string"` in php is parsed to get "valueofstring". PHP eliminates the strain for concatinating strings when you have to insert a string literal.

```
"something" . $string . "somethingelse" 
"something{$string}somethingelse"
```

both are the same.

For clarity in longer strings it is adviced you use with the braces `{}` as `"{$string}"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "World"
echo "Hello $var" // Output "Hello World"
echo 'Hello $var' // Output "Hello $var"
```

Double quotes replace variable content.

If you have an array you have to do something more:

```
$var = array("World")
echo "Hello {$var[0]}" // Output "Hello World"
```

Note the angle brackets {} betwenn $var[0]

Answer (score -1):

the first your just passing the strings to the connection as if $username was your actual username, the latter your passing the value of the variable $username which will equal what has been set at an earlier time with $username = "myUsername"

Comment: Quoting the variables in PHP casts them as strings, though they are already strings.  It's simply a redundancy.  If they were _single-quoted_ rather than double, then the username would be literally `$username`

Comment: Ahh, I though you needed to surround them with {} for it to be recognized as a string.  Been a long time..